# Solving a 2nd order nonlinear ODE through substitution based linearisation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have the following nonlinear differential equation,

$$y y''-(y')^2-yy'(\alpha y-\beta)=0,\qquad (\ast)$$

and I was wondering whether it would be possible to linearise it?

Whilst browsing the web, I came across this equation:

$$y y''-(y')^2+f(x)yy'+g(x)y^2=0,$$

which I [link](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0335.pdf) here, which may be solved through the substitution $u=y'/y$.

They are astoundingly similar and I was therefore curious as to whether my equation $(\ast)$ can also be solved through a similar process of linearisation. I have not made the breakthrough so far and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is of that form if I understood brackets right. Take $f(x)=\beta$ and $g(x)=-\alpha$

Comment: @Somnium in that case, we still don't get the $\alpha y^2y'$ term in $(\ast)$

Comment: You right, I overlooked it.

Answer (score 1):

In the second-order autonomous case it helps sometimes to draw the eye towards useful substitutions by reparametrizing $y'=u(y)$, on solution segments where that is admissible. Then $y''=u'(y)u(y)$ and thus
$$
yuu'-u^2+yu(αy−β)=0
$$
As a first step, one can divide by $u$, as $y'\ne 0$ is a condition for the substitution.
$$
yu'-u+y(αy−β)=0
$$
This now is linear in $u$ with integrating factor $1/y^2$
$$
\left(\frac{u}{y}\right)'+α-\frac{β}{y}=0\implies y'=u=βy\ln|y|-αy^2+\gamma y
$$
Try next $y=Ce^{v}$ to get
$$
v'=β(\ln|C|+v)-αCe^v+γ.
$$
I see no further way to transform this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, when I divide the second equation by $1/y^2$, I get an additional $u/y^2$ term

Comment: Remind yourself of the quotient rule, all terms are accounted for.